# PDF of sum of (1/(1+uniform distribution)) and a normal distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, convolution

I have a continuous uniform random variable $P∼U(0,1)$ and a normal random variable $X∼N(0,σ)$. If $Z$ is given by $Z=\frac{1}{1+P}+X$ where $X$ and $P$ are independent variables, how can I calculate the PDF of $Z$ in Mathematica?

This fails to run:

```
pdf3 = PDF[
  TransformedDistribution[(1/(1 + z1)) + 
    z2, {z1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
    z2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s]}], x]
```

However, if I look only at $Z = \frac{1}{1+P}$ using a similar approach, my code runs OK:

```
pdf2 = PDF[
  TransformedDistribution[(1/(1 + z1)), {z1 \[Distributed] 
     UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}], x]
```

Comment: try `td1 = TransformedDistribution[(1/(1 + z1)), {z1 \[Distributed] 
     UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}];
pmd = ParameterMixtureDistribution[NormalDistribution[m1, s], 
   m1 \[Distributed] td1, Assumptions -> s > 0];
PDF[pmd]@x`?

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, still does not run. Thank you for trying!

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134911/pdf-of-sum-of-1-1uniform-distribution-and-a-normal-distribution.

Answer (score 3):

I know you want an explicit formula for the pdf but I'm not sure that exists.  Here's why:

Your `pdf2` is

```
pdf2 = PDF[TransformedDistribution[(1/(1 + z1)), 
  {z1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}], z2]
```

[image: pdf of 1/(1-p)]

So the brute force approach would be to get the pdf of $Z$ as follows:

```
Integrate[(1/z1^2) PDF[NormalDistribution[0, s], z - z1], {z1, 1/2, 1}, Assumptions -> s > 0]
```

But the input is just returned and even using [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) doesn't get an explicit solution.  A numerical approach might be what you have to do.

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[(1/(1 + z1)) + 
    z2, {z1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
    z2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s]}];

pdf[z_, s_] := NIntegrate[(1/z2^2) PDF[NormalDistribution[0, s], z - z2], {z2, 1/2, 1}]

s0 = 1/80;
n = 100000;
SeedRandom[12345];
zz = RandomVariate[dist /. s -> s0, n];
Show[Histogram[zz, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"], 
 Plot[pdf[z, s0], {z, 0.4, 1.1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Histogram and estimated density]

Comment: Should that be a `z1` rather than a `u` in the normal distribution PDF in your second code block?  (If not, it's a pretty easy integral.)  :-)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert.  You're right.  I changed the notation and then didn't run it again which would have caught that error.  I'll fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I feared that there might not be a way to get an explicit solution with Mathematica. Do you think this is a limitation of the software or something about the function itself that prevents the convolution of the PDFs?

Comment: For anyone interested, I also have a post on math.stackexchange on finding the PDF of the same equation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134911/pdf-of-sum-of-1-1uniform-distribution-and-a-normal-distribution

Comment: The integral resembles [`OwenT`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwenT.html), but I was unable to massage the integrand to express it in terms of it.